# Realm and UserDefaults - App Versions and Update

Tags: swift, realm, userdefaults

I'm trying to search the answer for the scenarios -

I want to replace Realm (database) to UserDefaults. I'll be doing by -

the next version (2.0) of ios app will copy the data in Realm over to UserDefaults.
(3.0) will remove realm from pods

Will the user lose the data if he/she forgot to update the 2.0 and goes with 3.0?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You definitely do not want to use UserDefaults in that fashion - it's not what it was designed to do. See the official documentation [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). *The defaults system allows an app to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences* - with the stress on *preferences* like preferred unit of measurement or default playback speed. That being said, the question is pretty unclear - what does *remove realm from pods* mean? What does 2.0 and 3.0 represent? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Got it, looks like I need to learn Core Data or hold on this idea off. I wanted to get it natively as possible (no third libraries). For the 2.0, and 3.0, it is a build version - my concern is that if I uploaded the release of 2.0 in app store and they updated the app with the copied data over to Core Data, then I uploaded the app with build number of 3.0 with uninstalled realm in pods. My question if the user skipped the build number of 2.0 and updated the app with 3.0, will he/she have an error or lose the data?

Comment: I don't know the use case but there's no general reason to move to CoreData from Realm. Realm is a perfectly capable and scaleable database that also provides multi-user support with sync'ing - options not available in CoreData.